# Stored Procedure with Snowflake Scripting to Insert Data

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert from a table to another table in Snowflake. I want to use a stored procedure to do this so that I can insert data for the dates that I need when I need them. I'm trying to figure out how to write a stored procedure using Snowflake scripting that accomplishes what I need it to, but nothing is working. I'm a new user to Snowflake so I don't 100% get Snowflake scripting. I also am most familiar with SQL, which is why I was sticking to Snowflake Scripting. Please, I would appreciate any help.

This is an example of the query I want in my stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (id, value, asOfDate, LastUpdated) 
-- AsOfDate is a variable.
VALUES
SELECT (id, value, asOfDate, getDate())
From t2
     JOIN t3
WHERE @AsOfDate = AsofDate
```

This is what I tried in Snowflake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT()
  RETURNS TABLE
  LANGUAGE SQL

AS
DECLARE AsOfDate DATE;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO table (id, value, AsOfDate, LastUpdated)
VALUES
SELECT :id, :value, :AsOfDate, :GETDATE()
FROM t1
  JOIN t2
  JOIN t3
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
AND AsOfDate = :AsOfDate

RETURN "success"
END;
```

I keep getting the errror message: 'Syntax error: unexpected 'INTO'.'
Please, I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `INSERT INTO VALUES SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value, AsOfDate, LastUpdated)
VALUES
SELECT :id, :value, :AsOfDate, :GETDATE()
FROM t1
  JOIN t2
  JOIN t3
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
AND AsOfDate = :AsOfDate
```

should rather be `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value, AsOfDate, LastUpdated)
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t1.AsOfDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
FROM t1
  JOIN t2 ON ...
  JOIN t3 ON ...
WHERE t1.id IS NOT NULL
  AND t1.AsOfDate = :AsOfDate;
```

Also:

`GETDATE()` => `CURRENT_DATE()/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Each column should be prefixed with table name/alias it originated from.

Answer (score -1):

I am having same problem and was unable to find any solution. Even though in the official documentation [How to Write Stored Procedure in Snowflake-Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/stored-procedure/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting#calling-a-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure), They have used 'INSERT' Command. But the trick is they are only using 'INSERT' command (no select statement). So for insert statement we have to compulsorily use 'VALUES' Like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT()
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE SQL

AS
DECLARE 
INSERT_QUERY STRING;

BEGIN

**INSERT INTO int_table VALUES (:value);**

RETURN 'SUCCESS';

END;
```

But if you try to use 'SELECT' Statement with 'INSERT'Query, then we 'VALUES' is not used in the command that gives the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT()
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE SQL

AS
DECLARE 
INSERT_QUERY STRING;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO TABLE_TEST
SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.CALL_CENTER;

RETURN 'SUCCESS';

END;
```

So to avoid this error. I Converted the 'INSERT' Query into String Statement and execute it using 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' Command. I assume you have also used the same method but still mentioning it. So that any person searching for the solution can save his/her/their time.

Example Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT()
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE SQL

AS
DECLARE 
INSERT_QUERY STRING;

BEGIN

INSERT_QUERY := 'INSERT INTO TABLE_TEST VALUES (:VALUE);
SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.CALL_CENTER';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INSERT_QUERY;


RETURN 'SUCCESS';

END;

CALL SP_INSERT();
```

Comment: insert from select can work in a procedure. I'm not seeing what's throwing an error in your example though.